# select_tag rails, show only particular list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, html-select

I have this model for company

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name, :type
   belongs_to :type, :class_name => "CompanyType", :foreign_key => :company_type_id
end
```

And this model for company_type

```
class CompanyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

then in another _form file I want to create a select which only show list of company where type of company is "Financial". If the type of that company is "Oil" then don't show it in the drop down list.

How do I insert it into this select_tag code and change the model?

```
<%= select_tag :company, 
    options_from_collection_for_select(Company.order(:name), "id", "name"),
    :include_blank => true%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag :company, 
options_from_collection_for_select(Company.where(:type => "Financial").order(:name), "id", "name"),
:include_blank => true%>
```

Basically just add .where(:type => "Financial"), you can add a simple .where statement in there. Though you might want to remove

```
Company.where(:type => "Financial").order(:name)
```

to your controller and save it in an instances variable like this

```
@companies = Company.where(:type => "Financial").order(:name)
```

and have the view logic look like this.

```
<%= select_tag :company, 
options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name"),
:include_blank => true%>
```

EDIT TO THE UPDATED QUESTION

Model

```
class CompanyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Controller

```
@companies = CompanyType.where(:name => "Financial").companies.order(:name)
```

and have the view logic look like this.

```
<%= select_tag :company, 
options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name"),
:include_blank => true%>
```

Comment: Updated it for your new question.